# Can not connect through ssh from one Debian server to another

Tags: ssh

Can not connect through ssh from one Debian server to another:

```
ssh user45@111.222.333.444 -p port_number

ssh: connect to host 111.222.333.444 port port_number: Connection timed out
```

I am doing something wrong? I can connect from Putty in my home computer but not from another server.

Comment: What settings do you use in putty?

Comment: iptables --list, check on both servers, maybe one is blocking input or another is blocking output

Comment: @WigglerJtag Don't you think that's a bit premature?

Comment: That would be the first thing I would check first.

Comment: Or routing. Or something else. Impossible to figure out with this limited information.

Comment: Is not port number blocked by something? What is your actual port number?

Comment: Tried to connect from server A to server B. from server B to server C. From server C to server A. The same problem - timeoiut. In Putty I use default settings. I just change port number because ssh is running on a custom ports.

Comment: Everything is working as designed/configured.

Comment: Wiggler Jtag, thanks. It was the port problem. It was not allowed by firewall.

Answer (score 1):

A timed out connection like that is indicative of a firewall at the other side dropping your packets. It probably requires that your IP be whitelisted.